# Why is PyPy (without JIT) slower than CPython

Tags: python, performance, pypy

recently i'm doing some performance tests with PyPy (Compared to CPython)

I use the nested loop matrix multiplication from this site: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/examples/multiply-matrix

I execute it 1 mio. times and measure the time with timeit.

With CPython it takes about 10s to finish.
With PyPy it only takes about 0.7s to finish.

This result is exactly what i would expect. Just out of curiousity i *disabled JIT* in PyPy and ran the test again.
Now PyPy takes about **80s** to finish the test.

So right now i am wondering why PyPy is extremely slow without JIT?
(I know disabling JIT is not how PyPy should be used, but i want to understand why it so slow without JIT)

Comment: It says written in RPython, so is probably missing a lot of optimisations over CPython.

Comment: [The documentation](https://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/architecture.html#pypy-interpreter) says about the interpreter "Some modules that CPython implements in C are simply written in pure Python". They apparently had no motivation for writing an optimized interpreter. Why should they when JIT is the target?

Comment: Your thoughts are reasonable, but that would mean that even basic math operations on lists are not optimised

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyPy. PyPy is a JIT with an implementation written in RPython. RPython is slower when interpreted compared to calling C functions like CPython does (an interpreted Python code cannot compete with an optimized compiled code), but quite fast when it is JITed. RPython has been designed so it can be fast only when the JIT is used. Disabling the JIT is a feature only used to debug PyPy itself (typically by PyPy's developers). Moreover, the JIT is a bit slower to execute C code due to the interfacing (the same apply with most JIT compilers).